# Can we use Google Translate API to index files for searching?

Tags: lucene, analyzer, query-analyzer

I am using Lucene 4.2.1 to index files. I need to index multilingual content for which we use Analyzer based on the language, to tokenize and index keywords. However Lucene 4.2.1 does not have analyzers for some languages like Japanese, Korean. The one solution to this is updating the lucene version but since that involves a lot of changes for deprecated functions (in case), I'm trying to find a work around. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Personally i would strongly suggest to invest this amount of time and upgrade to the most recent version. This "problem" is already solved in the never versions and building an own written solution may be much more time consuming than upgrading.

IMAO working with such an old version is a technical dept which should be solved. Technical dept always fires back and usually costs much more money as longer as they exist.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes I understand that upgrading it to the latest version should solve it better. Any suggestions on using APIs to index and search in other languages? I found some APIs created by WikiBrain but not sure how to use it in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure - But Got This on Google. The Google Cloud Translation API can dynamically translate text between thousands of language pairs. The Cloud Translation API lets websites and programs integrate with the translation service programmatically. The Google Translation API is part of the larger Cloud Machine Learning API family. Please Refer Here Too https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/ [Cotton bags supplier in Dubai](http://www.greenbagsuae.com)

Comment: Thanks for your help Yousuf! Actually I also need to index search files based on the data provided by my application. In that case the Google translate feature might not prove to be useful.